# Incorrect No of Icons Assigned in reactablefmtr icon_assign

Tags: r, reactable

The attached code should present the number of blue circles (between 0 and 4) based on the responseCount, but it doesn't.  I can't see why.

I always want there to be 4 in total (blue + grey) even when the selection has a lower maximum.

[image]

```
library(reactable)
library(reactablefmtr)
areas <- data.frame(name = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"))
areas$responseCount <- round(runif(nrow(areas), min = 0, max = 1) * 4)

reactable(
  areas,
  columns = list(
    responseCount = colDef(name = "Responses",
                           cell = icon_assign(areas, buckets = 4, 
                                              show_values = "left")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: It would seem that on the above simple example, if I remove the buckets = 4 then it works.  However, with my full data I then get the following error.  All my data is INT and in the range 0-4 with no nulls. Error in seq.default(1, max_value, by = seq_by) :  wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: I've found the issue.  Buckets are only needed if grouping values into segments, not if the number of icons should reflect that actual value of the field (as I do).  My list of items is nested within another list.  When one of the nested lists has zero values for all and buckets has not been included, it produces the wrong sign in seq 'by' argument.  Now I just need to figure out how to stop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the issue where if all values are zero and buckets has not been included, it produces the wrong sign in seq 'by' argument error to the reactablefmtr package owner Kyle Cuilla.

Kyle speedily pushed an update to dev that fixes it :)

So now the following works...

```
library(reactable)
remotes::install_github("kcuilla/reactablefmtr", force = TRUE)
library(reactablefmtr)
areas <- data.frame(name = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"))
areas$responseCount <- round(runif(nrow(areas), min = 0, max = 1) * 4)

reactable(
  areas,
  columns = list(
    responseCount = colDef(name = "Responses",
                           cell = icon_assign(areas,
                                              show_values = "left")
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i think reactablefmtr needs integer values rather than decimals.

try

```
areas$responseCount <- sample(0L:4L, nrow(areas))
```

also set a seed while using runif() for consistent output.

Comment: It would need to be areas$responseCount <- sample(0L:4L, nrow(areas), replace = TRUE).  Icons are displayed the same, so problem persists.